# Deleting Files in a Zip Archive on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, compression

I have a situation where I need to be able to run a script and delete specific files within a zip archive. Below is the general setup

```
/mnt/directory
/mnt/directory/Folder1
/mnt/directory/Folder1/file1.zip
/mnt/directory/Folder1/file2.zip
/mnt/directory/Folder2
/mnt/directory/Folder2/Documents
/mnt/directory/Folder2/file1.zip
/mnt/directory/Folder2/file2.zip
```

Then within each zip file, there are a lot of files and directories. There could be 20+ directories deep so I need to make sure whatever I do recursively looks into the files.

I have played with the *zipinfo -1 /mnt/directory/Folder1/file1.zip '*.txt'* command it finds all .txt files in file1.zip, but I can't wildcard the zipinfo command to make it search all zip files. Also, I still need to be able to delete them after the fact. I have also tested *zip -d /mnt/directory/Folder1/file1.zip filename.txt*. This works fine for 1 file and 1 file only, as long as it's not within a folder. So again, not ideal for my situation.

I can unzip them if needed, but would prefer not as some are very large and I will have to zip them back anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: use find. find /mnt/directory -name "*.zip" and pipe it to unzip.

Comment: I've tried "find /mnt/directory -name "*.zip" | zipinfo -1 "*.doc" and it doesn't work because it's not reading the zip files.

Comment: zipinfo do not accepts pipes. Try for i in $(find -iname "*.zip*"); do zipinfo $i;done

Comment: I got it workings with your recommendations above. This is my final output for the find command "find /mnt/directory/ -name "*.zip" -exec sh -c 'zipinfo -1 "{}" | grep -P "docx"' \;". Now my issue is I need to know what zip file the docx files come from. Currently it is just giving me the file names.

Comment: From my approach, i has the name of the zip file, so adding a echo $i should be enought. You can try find mnt/directory/ -name "*.zip" -exec sh -c 'zipinfo -1 "{}" | grep -P "docx"; echo "filename: "  "{}"'

Answer (score 0):

The module [Archive::Zip](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Archive-Zip-1.30/lib/Archive/Zip.pm) looks like it will do what you need.